# asp.net mvc 5 form post doesn't work

Tags: html, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a trouble with submiting a form in asp.net mvc 5. When I use razor Html.BeginForm() it creates a form with empty action and it doesn't work. When I use html code  it opens new page "site.com/Home/NewDeck" with error 404

Both of the following view's codes don't work.

This is view code (with Html.BeginForm()):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("NewDeck", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class="popup-form"}))
    {

        <div class="popup-header-row">
            <div style="display:flex; margin: 0; width: 24px"></div> @*pseudo element*@
            <div class="popup-header">New deck</div>
            <img id="btn-close-new-deck" src="~/Content/images/close.svg" class="close-button" />
        </div>

        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.NewDeck.Name, new { @placeholder = "Name of the deck", @class = "input-text-form" })

        <input type="submit" value="Add deck" class="btn-one-center" />
    }
```

This is view code (with form):

```
    <form method="post" action="/Home/NewDeck" class="popup-form">
        <div class="popup-header-row">
            <div style="display:flex; margin: 0; width: 24px"></div> @*pseudo element*@
            <div class="popup-header">New deck</div>
            <img id="btn-close-new-deck" src="~/Content/images/close.svg" class="close-button" />
        </div>

        @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.NewDeck.Name, new { @placeholder = "Name of the deck", @class = "input-text-form" })

        <input type="submit" value="Add deck" class="btn-one-center" />

    </form>
```

This is HomeController code:

```
    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        Model = new HomeViewModel { DeckList = Database.GetDecksList("mail@gmail.com") };
        Model.NewDeck = new Deck { Random = false };         
        return View(Model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewDeck(HomeViewModel model)
    {
        Database.AddDeck(model.NewDeck.Name, "mail@gmail.com", model.NewDeck.Random);
        return View(model);
    }
```

Comment: what is happening when you have `Html.BeginForm("NewDeck", "Home"`  ? When you use that, you should remove the inside form as nested forms are invalid!

Comment: @Shyju Html.BeginForm() is commented

Comment: I am saying why not use that ? The helper will set the action attribute value properly than you hardcoding and getting 404. Just use that and remove the inside form.

Comment: @Shyji I don't use these together. I've updated the question. Both don't work

Comment: So what is happening when you click on the submit button now ? Your code works fine for me. it does a form submit. Do you have some js code hijacking the submit/click event. ?

Comment: @Shyji When I click submit button with Html.BeginForm() I get 404 with "Requested URL: /". With form I get 404.0 (Error Code 0x80070002).
I don't have any js code for the submit button

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have some problem with your routing or parameter, as the form is not currently hitting your desired Action.

Try to replace the parameter in your action with some string value just for debugging and name it as 'sample'and in your form put a text field with name= 'sample', It will help you find out if that is the problem with your parameter passing or routing, if that works fine then you need to rethink the model you are passing from your View or maybe recheck your routes.

Also check your values in the database, if they are being updated then the error of 'form opening a new page in the new tab with 404 (not found)' is because your POST action is returning a View that should be a GET View and there is not GET Action in your Controller with the same name.

so put a Get Action with the same name as of your post action